# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'url_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, mysql-error-1048

I am getting this error in Zend Framework:
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'url_id' cannot be null

My code is:

```
$stmt = $this->select()->where('url_address = ?', $url_address)->query();       
        $r = $stmt->fetchAll();              
        print_r($r);
        if(count($r)==0){

            $data = array(
                'url_address'      => $url_address,
            );

            $this->insert($data);       

            $stmt = $this->select()->where('url_address = ?', $url_address)->query();                               
                         $r = $stmt->fetchAll();    

        }   

        echo $r->url_id;
        return $r->url_id;
```

Comment: Did you try putting something in `url_id`?

Comment: url_id is auto-increment, primary key

Comment: That's not what that error is saying...

Comment: I am getting error on Line 12 $r = $stmt->fetchAll();

Comment: It's not an auto-increment if it's showing that error

Answer (score -1):

That's a MySQL error, not really a PHP one.  You need the url_id field to be a default value of NULL if nothing is going to be inserted there.

Comment: My problem solved

The error was due to this line: $r->url_id;

return $r[0]["url_id"];

Comment: @FutureKing could you please elaborate on how you solved this problem? Possibly even post as an answer?